# Customizing device installation settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, windows-update, control-panel

Windows 7's Windows Update device driver update settings can be configured in Control Panel - Devices and Printers - Device installation settings:

(click image to view full, larger image)
[image: Windows 7's Windows Update device driver update settings can be configured in Control Panel - Devices and Printers - Device installation settings]

What are the differences between these settings? Especially, between the *'Yes, do this automatically'* option and  the *'No, let me choose what to do - Always install the best driver software from Windows Update'* option.

Also, what is the difference between the first two *'No, let me choose what to do'* options (will both settings install drivers from Windows Update, if Windows Update has a more updated version than the one found in the computer?).

Edit: The reason for these questions is: I'd like to set Windows Update to install and automatically update my integrated sound card drivers and LAN card/Network adapter drivers as I prefer Windows Update to my motherboard's driver update software, which doesn't update properly. (Windows Update drivers work fine with my integrated sound card and LAN Card/Network adapter.) I am looking for the best option for this, hence, I would like to know the differences between these settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "always install the best driver software..." option under the *let me choose* options probably is there to allow automatic driver downloads but to disable the enhanced driver icons.

Comment: This could be, although the checkbox for the *'Replace generic icons with enhanced icons'* can still be checked if you choose '*No, let me choose what to do'*. So if you choose *'No...*' and check that box, then is it the same as choosing *'Yes, do this automatically'*?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do this automatically - Automatically downloads the latest drivers and icons. If the latest drivers are the same as the ones already installed on your machine it will just use the ones on your machine.

If you choose no . . .
Always install the best driver from Windows Update -  Anytime Windows needs a driver, it goes to Windows Update and downloads the latest one.

Install blah blah blah - Obviously, if you already have the latest one on your computer, it just loads that one.

Never install from Windows Update - Self explanatory.

Either way, if Windows can't find the driver, it will prompt you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the differences? It seems to me that *Yes, do this automatically* and *No... Always install the best driver from Windows Update* are basically the same.

Comment: Also, please elaborate on the difference between the first two *'No...'* options too. From what I can tell, it seems that they will both install the latest drivers from Windows Update. What are their differences in behavior and in what circumstances?

Comment: Yes, do this automatically == Install driver software.  Always install best driver from Windows Update will override the initial search through the local driver storage. This is essentially an rollup of about five different Group Policies. What situations are you running into?

Comment: I'd like to set Windows Update to install and automatically update my integrated sound card drivers and LAN card/Network adapter drivers as I prefer Windows Update to my motherboard's driver update software, which doesn't update properly. (Windows Update drivers work fine with my integrated sound card and LAN Card/Network adapter.) I am looking for the best option for this, hence, I would like to know the differences between these settings.

Comment: Then select the always install best driver from Windows Update.

Comment: I just tried setting it to `No... > Always install the best driver from Windows Update` and then saving it, but Windows sets the radio button for `Yes, do this automatically` to on, the next time I open Device Installation settings, leading me to believe that they have no difference. This does not happen with the other two *'No, let me choose what to do'* options.