# Wrong driver gets installed over and over again

Tags: windows-10, drivers, tablet, hid

I need to remove the automatically installed driver of a device before I can install the proper/required driver. So far, I used the "Delete the driver software for this device" checkbox and I also used `pnputil` to remove the driver from the windows driver cache/storage. However, the device magically appears with the allegedly deleted driver again after the required reboot. The driver does also appear again in the driver cache. I am at a loss from where  windows restores that driver. How I can prevent that?

---

*Full story:*
I did a clean Windows 10 installation on a Lenovo Yoga Book Tablet. Lenovo's driver installation/update tool does not work for some reason on my particular device, so I installed all drivers manually. The driver for the so called "Halo Keyboard" has the following installation instruction:

```
1. You need to uninstall "Goodix Touch HID" first:
    a. Right click on the "Win" button on the left bottom corner of the desktop
    b. Click Device Manager --> Expand the "Human Interface Devices" tree
    c. Double click on the "Goodix Touch HID" item --> choose "Driver" tab
    d. Click "Uninstall" button --> select the "Delete the driver software 
       for this device" --> click "OK"
    e. if need restart, please follow the guide.

2. install KeyboardDriver 2.0.7.msi First.(need restart your computer)
3. install HaloKeyboard 2.0.7.msi Next.
4. install Multi-mode service 1.0.2.7.msi last.
5. restart your computer.
```

The *Goodix Touch HID* is the driver that is re-installed regardless of the procedure described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to a magic Windows function. Maybe the authors of the installation guide should have mentioned that the driver to be installed has exactly the same name as the driver to be removed, which makes it hard to tell if it was installed correctly.

If you still want to disable automatic driver installation, look here:

- [Disable automatic driver installation in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/954184/disable-automatic-driver-installation-in-windows-10)
- [Customizing device installation settings](https://superuser.com/questions/322189/customizing-device-installation-settings)

Comment: Please expand this to include enough detail to be useful to somebody else in the future.